# Python, function inside a function

Tags: python, function

```
def makebold(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"
    return wrapped

def message():
    return "TasPython Guide"

message = makebold(message)
print(message())
```

Well, I have many questions about the above code...

1st: why inside the wrapped() function we use the fn variable as a function? Shouldn't we use fn instead of fn() ?

2nd: why `message = makebold(message)` and not `message = makebold(message())`

3rd: why `print(message())`gives me this result???

I would expect something like: `print(makebold(message())`

Thank you guys!

Comment: Because `makebold` is a *decorator*. Read the question I duped you to, especially the highest-voted answer.

Comment: It seems you need to learn about something called decorators.Here you have a pretty neat and concise guide to understand it. Go straight to chapter no. 6. http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

Comment: Thanks @peluzza ! I 'll read it right after am done with the answers of Martinj Pieters!